# Creating key in java from password and salt using aes 256

Tags: java, c++, encryption, aes, jce

I am writing piece of code that decrypts data in java, which is encrypted in some C++ code using [poco lib] (http://pocoproject.org/docs/).

C++ code is similar as shown below:

```
std::string password = "secret";
std::string salt("asdff8723lasdf(**923412");
CipherKey key("aes-256", password, salt);
```

Also with iteration count of 2k.

```
DEFAULT_ITERATION_COUNT = 2000
```

How do I create that same key in java to decrypt the data?
What is equivalent code in java?

I am trying something like this,

```
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    char[] passowrd = "secret".toCharArray();
    byte[] salt = "asdff8723lasdf(**923412".getBytes();

    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passowrd,salt, 2000);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
```

But, it doesn't works. Gives me no such algorithm found exception. Which algorithm should I use? Do I need to know something more to decrypt?

**UPDATE**
I have added bounty castle to my security provider as pointed out by [user2504380](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2504380/user2504380)

Comment: What is the output of Security.getProviders() ?

Comment: This is the output :SUN version 1.7
SunRsaSign version 1.7
SunEC version 1.7
SunJSSE version 1.7
SunJCE version 1.7
SunJGSS version 1.7
SunSASL version 1.7
XMLDSig version 1.0
SunPCSC version 1.7
SunMSCAPI version 1.7

Comment: Dont you miss the BouncyCastle Security Provider there?

Comment: In providers? nope that's complete list.

Comment: No, i mean, i dont see bouncycastle, habe you installed it? Because you need to have, as far, as i know from older java versions.

Comment: Possibly duplicate: [Java 256-bit AES Password-Based Encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption)

Comment: One major differnce is creating key from password and salt with which i am struggling right now